How to Dynamically Filter Second Dropdown Based on First Dropdown Selection in jira insight CMDB?
How to Dynamically Filter Second Dropdown Based on First Dropdown Selection in jira insight CMDB?
Jira CMDB Insight objects configuration allows aql attribute filtering in the config cog near cardinality. But the AQL query I use for filtering is not working.
I have 3 tables/objects with the fallowing attributes:

User ( name:str, email:str, OrganizationName: ofType Organization)
Organization (name:str, location:str etc)
LeptopAssets (organizationUsingTheAsset: ofType Organization, userUsingTheAsset: ofType User)

When adding LeptotAssets objects/entries, if I select the organizationUsingTheAsset = xxx in the first droptown, I need in the next dropdown 'userUsingTheAsset' to see only users belonging to that xxx selected organization.
In LeptopAssets, I tried filtering the values for userUsingTheAsset dropdown field based on the value selected in organizationUsingTheAsset dropdown like this and failed:
object having outboundReferences(objectType = "organizationUsingTheAsset", referenceType IN ("BelongsTo"))
where belongsTo is the Additional Value I use for that field.
I pasted the AQL filter in the Attributes > config cog > Config > Filter Objects section of that specific object

So upon creation of a new LeptopAsset object need to allow assigning that laptop asset only to a person that belongs to the org selected in the previous dropdown field.
https://confluence.atlassian.com/servicemanagementserver/advanced-searching-aql-assets-query-language-1044784588.html
